# jquery can't get a webservice response

Tags: php, jquery, web-services, gps

So... I'm ordered :'( to create a information system for a heavy machinery rent firm, wich have a GPS for every machine, the data from the GPS is prvided by another an external firm wich uses a web services. (I'm very lost with these project...)

I need to (load at least) read data from a web service, to populate a DB with it, the web service respond comma separated data, and in another cases it respond the same, but is a .txt inside a .zip.

so when it just echoes the in a  page... it seems like these:

```
0
739,-70.61692,-33.44053,0,0,2005-10-03 13:54:15.0,Cada 00:02:00 hh:mm:ss.
739,-70.61685,-33.44038,0,0,2005-10-03 13:19:00.0,Detención Mayor a 2 Min.
739,-70.61682,-33.44040,0,0,2005-10-03 13:14:47.0,Cada 00:02:00 hh:mm:ss.
739,-70.61685,-33.44040,0,0,2005-10-03 12:56:09.0,Detención Mayor a 2 Min.
739,-70.61683,-33.44037,0,0,2005-09-21 03:19:23.0,Cada 00:02:00 hh:mm:ss.
739,-70.61738,-33.44057,0,0,2005-09-21 03:16:45.0,Detención Mayor a 2 Min.
739,-70.62070,-33.44182,0,0,2005-09-21 03:14:41.0,Cada 00:02:00 hh:mm:ss.
739,-70.62060,-33.44165,0,0,2005-09-21 03:09:44.0,Cada 00:02:00 hh:mm:ss.
739,-70.61685,-33.44040,0,0,2005-09-21 01:05:31.0,Cada 00:02:00 hh:mm:ss.
……
……
……
739,-70.61687,-33.44040,0,0,2005-09-21 01:00:35.0,Cada 00:02:00 hh:mm:ss.
739,-70.61685,-33.44038,0,0,2005-09-21 00:56:02.0,Detencion Mayor a 2 Min.
FIN
```

the zipped data looks exactly like that.
But I can't even manage to load the data, so How am I supposed to work with it, i.e. use it to feed a database (which is actually what I want to do)

the Jquery code I'm using looks like these:

```
  $("a").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var webdir = $(this).attr("href");
      alert("I'm supposed to load the following URL: "+webdir);       
      $.ajax({
      url: webdir,
      success: function(data){
          $('#resultado').html(data);
          alert('Load was performed.');
      }
      }).fail(function(){ 
      alert("error"); 
      });//this at least throws an error
  });
```

[-you can see a working (failing to be honest) example-](http://jsbin.com/abuliv/4)

And I'm not even capable to get the data, and I don't even know if I need to get the data using jquery, or if I have to get it using PHP....
so please, help me with the jquery... then if you have time, point in the right direction on how to populate a DB with data from a WEB service like these.

Comment: Does this really need to be done with client side code? Either way the sql part will have to be done with php, you mightaswell just request it with php unless that data needs to also be on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Always look at your browser's JavaScript error console.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.entelgps.cl/webservices/api_pos/ApiPos.cfc?method=ObtenerPosiciones&usuario=77421750-9&password=7742&fecha=20120822&hora_inicio=12:30:00&hora_fin=13:10:00.
>   Origin http://jsbin.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Essentially, the problem is that JavaScript AJAX requests are not allowed to request content from a different domain name.

Comment: so I'm totally lost here?
I was looking for another questions right here in stackoverflow, and
they seem to have to same problem...

Comment: dude from my server it doesn't get the acces control alow origin.

Comment: Show us the page running on your server, then, so we can reasonably troubleshoot.